# How do I use Fabric to SSH to two different ports on the same server?

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm trying to use Fabric (v1.3.4) to provision Karaf instances on various servers.  Karaf implements an SSH server.  So, I have 2 ssh daemons running on the same server; one on port 22 and one on 8101. Using the fabric.tasks.execute() method of Fabric, I can connect to an alternative host:port.

The problem is, my initial session becomes hijacked by the named user of the second connection due to an apparent hijacking of env.user.

Here's a simplified fabfile.py example:

```
from fabric.api import env, run
from fabric.tasks import execute

env.hosts = ['192.168.5.250']

def firstSSH():
        run("echo first")
        executeHosts = []
        for host in env.hosts:
                executeHosts.append("notmmaley@" + host + ":8101")
        execute(secondSSH, hosts=executeHosts)
        run("echo first again")

def secondSSH():
    run("echo second", shell=False, pty=False)
```

Both SSH servers are on the same server, with on two different ports and allowing for two different users.  Here is the output:

```
~/fabric$ fab firstSSH
[192.168.5.250] Executing task 'firstSSH'
[192.168.5.250] run: echo first
[192.168.5.250] Login password:
[192.168.5.250] out: first

[notmmaley@192.168.5.250:8101] Executing task 'secondSSH'
[notmmaley@192.168.5.250:8101] run: echo second
[notmmaley@192.168.5.250:8101] Login password:
[notmmaley@192.168.5.250:8101] out: second

[notmmaley@192.168.5.250:8101] run: echo first again

Done.
Disconnecting from 192.168.5.250:8101... done.
Disconnecting from mmaley@192.168.5.250... done.
```

Note how the "echo first again" is executed as the notmmaley user that was specified strictly for hosts of the execute() command.  What I want (need) is for the execute() command to occur as named user for the specified *user@host:port* and then return the original user to me for the remaining tasks.  Is this possible with Fabric/execute() and/or where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is an issue addressed in [Bug 568](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/568), which is patched in Fabric 1.4.1+. You should update to the newest and see if this addresses your issue. On a side note you might be better served by doing this for your host manipulation:

```
execute(secondSSH, hosts=["notmmaley@%s:8101" % h for h in env.hosts])
```

As you're not making any vars, or simple for loops to populate them.

Comment: Thank you for the link to that bug reference.  I have been in touch with bitprophet and it was restated that this behavior was due to an intended feature.  It looks like the fix might provide a solution, which I will try.  Thanks also for the suggestion on how to tighten up the code.  I'm new to Python, so this is quite helpful!